# Почему функция активации Sigmoid работает, а ReLU - нет?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

Есть такой код:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot

# задаем для воспроизводимости результатов
numpy.random.seed(2)

# разбиваем датасет на матрицу параметров (X) и вектор целевой переменной (Y)
X = array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])

Y = array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T

# создаем модели, добавляем слои один за другим
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=3, activation='relu')) # входной слой требует задать input_dim


# компилируем модель, используем градиентный спуск adam
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

# обучаем нейронную сеть
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 10000, batch_size=4)

# оцениваем результат
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
pre = model.predict(array([[0, 1, 0]]))
print(pre)

precl = model.predict_classes(array([[1,0,0]]))
print(precl)
```

И когда я использую функцию активации *ReLU*, то точность никогда не растет выше 50% и ответы получаются неправильными. Когда я использую *Sigmoid*, все сходится сразу же.

Я читал, что *ReLU* сейчас является предпочтительной в большинстве случаев. Что не так в моём случае?

Результаты (должно быть: 0, 1):

Для *ReLU*:

```
accuracy: 50.00%
[[0.9953842]]
[[0]]
```

Для *Sigmoid*:

```
accuracy: 100.00%
[[0.13338517]]
[[1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разные функции активации применяются в разных случаях. Как всегда, не существует <s>серебрянной пули</s> универсальной функции активации.

`ReLU` (Rectified Limear Unit) обычно используется для *скрытых слоев* НС, но **не** для *выходного слоя*.

В вашем случае вы построили модель бинарной классификации, которая должна на выходе выдавать вероятность позитивного исхода (при бинарной классификации у нас может быть либо негативный `False` либо позитивный `True` результат). Поэтому для задач бинарной классификации для **выходного слоя** удобно использовать [функцию сигмоиды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0) в качестве функции активации. Область значений сигмоиды: `(0, 1)` - как раз то что нужно для случая бинарной классификации.

**График сигмоиды:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**График ReLU:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS [статья на английском, помогающая понять различные функции активации](https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0)